# Flutter Provider is returning null in initState()

Tags: flutter, flutter-provider

I am getting List of DropdownMenuItem from firebase with stream using provider if I use provider in build it doesn't return null works great but in initstate even if I am setting the listen value false returns null.

Here is the code:

```
List<DropdownMenuItem<category.List>> dropdownmenuoptions;
DropdownMenuItem<category.List> dropdownMenuItem;
String dropDownValue;

@override
  void initState() {
    dropdownmenuoptions = Provider.of<List<DropdownMenuItem<category.List>>>(
        context,
        listen: false);
    dropdownMenuItem = dropdownmenuoptions.first;
    dropDownValue = dropdownMenuItem.value.name;
    super.initState();
  }
```

Here is the error message:

```
The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown building Builder:
The getter 'first' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: first
The relevant error-causing widget was
MaterialApp
lib/main.dart:37
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack
#0      Object.noSuchMethod (dart:core-patch/object_patch.dart:51:5)
#1      _HomeScreenState.initState
package:tobetter/…/home/home_screen.dart:73
#2      StatefulElement._firstBuild
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:4833
#3      ComponentElement.mount
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:4649
...     Normal element mounting (24 frames)
```

Comment: from where you are getting the context that you have used inside initiate state?

Comment: I am not getting from somewhere

Comment: You need a valid context to get value from provider. You have the context inside build method. That's why it is working inside build method.

Comment: ok I get it but need to use it outside the build method

Answer (score 3):

The direct `context` inside `initState` can't be used for everything and specialty with `Provider` . so, as a solution use `didChangeDependencies` instead , example:

```
  @override
  void didChangeDependencies() {
    super.didChangeDependencies();
    dropdownmenuoptions = Provider.of<List<DropdownMenuItem<category.List>>>(
        context,
        listen: false);
    dropdownMenuItem = dropdownmenuoptions.first;
    dropDownValue = dropdownMenuItem.value.name;
  }
```

if you really need it inside your `initState` you can use it inside `addPostFrameCallback`

```
@override
void initState(){
   ...
   SchedulerBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
     dropdownmenuoptions =  Provider.of<List<DropdownMenuItem<category.List>>>(
        context,
        listen: false);
     dropdownMenuItem = dropdownmenuoptions.first;
     dropDownValue = dropdownMenuItem.value.name;
}
});
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227006/discussion-on-answer-by-ikerfah-flutter-provider-is-returning-null-in-initstate).